# Spring websocket session start time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, spring-websocket

Is there any built-in property to get the start time of a Spring `WebSocketSession`? By start time i mean the time when the session started or when the websocket connection opened?

**UPDATE:**

I have a TestWebSocketService where I "store" the websocket session. And here I want to get informations about the session like session start time (connection start time) and so on.

WebSocketHandler:

```
@Component
public class TestWebsocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler{

    private final TestWebSocketService testWebSocketService;

    @Autowired
    public TestWebsocketHandler(TestWebSocketService testWebSocketService){
        this.testWebSocketService = testWebSocketService;
    }


    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {          

        this.testWebSocketService.setSession(session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage requestMessage) throws Exception {    
        ...
    }
}
```

WebSocketService:

```
@Component
public class TestWebSocketServiceImpl implements TestWebSocketService {

    private WebSocketSession session;

    public TestWebSocketServiceImpl() {}


    @Override
    public void setSession(WebSocketSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }   
}
```

Comment: you can get it using `HttpSession#getCreationTime()`  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getCreationTime--

Comment: @redflar3 How can I get the HttpSession?

Comment: can you give example of some code where you want to get the session start time

Answer (score 0):

I found an example here to [maintain session during websocket connection](http://www.devglan.com/faq/spring-session-stomp-websocket). Hope this helps